# Searching a User custom column in WordPress Admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a custom column for the address on the users page in WP. I am trying to search by username, email, and the address. Is there a good way to pass my custom column into my WP_User_Query to make it searchable?

```
    add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'billing_address_column', 20 );

    function billing_address_column( $user_columns ) {
 
    return array_slice( $user_columns, 0, 3, true ) 
    + array( 'billing_address' => 'Billing Address' ) 
    + array_slice( $user_columns, 3, NULL, true );
 
}

add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'populate_with_billing_address', 10, 3 );
function populate_with_billing_address( $row_output, $user_column_name, $user_id ) {
 
    if( $user_column_name == 'billing_address' ) {
 
        $address = array();
 
        if( $billing_state = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_state', true ) )
            $address[] = $billing_state;
 
        if( $billing_city = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', true ) )
            $address[] = $billing_city;
 
        if( $billing_postcode = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', true ) )
            $address[] = $billing_postcode;
 
        return join(', ', $address ); // here we replace and return our custom $row_output
 
    }
 
}

// WP_User_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'search_columns' => array( 'id', 'user_login', 'user_nicename', 'user_email', 'billing_address' ),
    'number'         => '200',
    'fields'         => 'all',
);

// The User Query
$zip_search = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```